# Sum up values in column using batch file

Tags: batch-file, sum

I'm a newbee to programming in batch-files on windows, so hopefully someone can help me:
I want to use a batch file to sum up all values of column 3 in a csv-file called 'TEST.csv':

```
01/01/2013;1;1342
01/01/2013;2;1484
01/01/2013;3;1528
```

After that, I want to use an if-statement: 
if the total sum of column 3 is unequal to 0, then start up a specific program `blabla.exe`

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Unless negative values are allowed, if any line has a non 0 value, there is no need to sum the data.

Answer (score 2):

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for /f "tokens=3 delims=;" %%a in (test.csv) do (
    set /a num=!num!+%%a
)
if !num! GTR 0 blabla.exe
```

To deal with decimals:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for /f "tokens=3 delims=;" %%a in (test.csv) do (
    set num=!num!+%%a
    )
    set num=!num:~1!
call :Eval !num! ret
if %ret% GTR 0 blabla.exe
exit /b

:Eval in out
setlocal
if exist eval.vbs del eval.vbs
>eval.vbs echo wsh.echo eval("%1")
for /f "delims=" %%a in ( 
  'cscript //nologo eval.vbs' 
) do endlocal & set %~2=%%a
del eval.vbs
```

Comment: Thanks. However, it doesn't work yet. It says 'missing operator' 6 times. Any idea why? I've checked the file and there are in this example 6 values unequal to zero. These 6 values have 3 decimals using '.' as decimal sign. Maybe that's the reason?

Comment: When I remove the decimals, it works! So, now I only need a way to deal with these decimals in the csv-file.

Comment: Batch and floating point math don't get along to well. I usually farm that out to a little vbscript function. See the above edit.

Comment: Thank you Matt. I managed to get generate an automatic test.csv-file with only integers, which makes it less complicated.